# Getting the Sequence Value of hibernate / Knowing the id hibernate inserted

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I have two tables. One table having sequence and other table does not. i need to use the same id which got inserted to second table for business purposes.

Currently im getting max using projections and incrementing it. using this value for insert in two tables.

i need to use sequence value of one table and insert the same value in another table? how this can be done ?

Comment: Rule #1: never `select max(id)` just to find out what id was last inserted. Rule #2: in Oracle, *no table has a sequence* - you have tables, and you have sequences, but there is no explicit link between the two.  Now - it's up to the Hibernate experts here to explain how to do this...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how hibernate will change this, but normally you can use the returning clause to get the value of data that was just inserted:

```
-- Create Objects
create table x
(id number, txt varchar2(50));

create table y
(id number, txt varchar2(50));

create sequence seq;

-- Insert into x, retrieve value of sequence used in insert
-- then use that to insert into y
declare
    v_seq NUMBER;
begin
    insert into x
    (id, txt)
    values
    (seq.nextval, 'test')
    returning id
    into v_seq;

    insert into y
    (id, txt)
    values
    (v_seq, 'test2');
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the ability to comment but your question isn't clear.

Many (all?) databases don't associate a sequence to table. I could do (pseudo-code):

```
CREATE TABLE x (value INT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE y (value INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO x (SELECT sequence_my_seq.nextval());
INSERT INTO y (SELECT sequence_my_seq.nextval());
```

Assuming you are using Java and have a Hibernate object and need to do something with the id generated by the INSERT statement outside of the Hibernate world:

Assume MyHibernateMappedObj is an object mapped in Hibernate:

```
MyHibernateMappedObj myHibernateObj = new MyHibernateMappedObj();
Assert.isNull(muHibernateObj.getId());

getCurrentHibernateSession().save(obj);

Assert.isNotNull(myHibernateObj.getId());

doSomethingWithNewId(myHibernateObj.getId());
```

then 'obj' will have its 'id' field populated. If your second table is mapped to the class/entityName in Hibernate Hibernate will take care of this for you.